# A simple alternative to smoothScatter(R) in python?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

Recently, I moved from R to python. Basically, I can quickly find a good alternative to R function in python except `smoothScatter`. I searched a lot and found these two answers helpful:

- [Generate a heatmap in MatPlotLib using a scatter data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set)
- [how does 2d kernel density estimation in python (sklearn) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577705/how-does-2d-kernel-density-estimation-in-python-sklearn-work)

But both of them are relatively complicated and slow compared to R (I have about 2,000,000 data points and `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` is really slow). So is there a simple python package can replace `smoothScatter` in R?

[image: smoothScatter in R]

[smoothScatter](http://rfunction.com/archives/595)

Comment: @cbuchart Thanks for helping me edit my question!(Although I am not sure if it is appropriate to say here, seems not relevant to question.) I will pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the exact same output, your plots remind me of `HexBin` plots, available through [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hexbin.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-hexbin), and [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/hexbin_marginals.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! But the problem is that `HexBin` result is not smooth enough...and when I try to increase bin number, it becomes very slow(seaborn is stuck...). I can calculate kernel density then plot in python but it needs many adjustments.  I am just wondering why there is not a simple Python package that can replace `smoothScatter` in R ...

Comment: weird, on my machine with two series of 2E6 points, seaborn takes ~5 sec to generate the hex jointplot.